# Password Doesn't match when login on laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

i make multi auth laravel on my project, but i have a problem, when member login back after few days, password doesn't match, passwords change by itself, whereas members do not make password changes, many a lot of members are reporting this issue to me

this is my login controller for members

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web\Members\MemberAuth;

// use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Session;
use DB;
use App\invoice;
use Redirect;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('RedirectIfMember', ['except' => 'logout']);

    }

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('web.members.signin');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if(Session::get('invoiceCODE')){
            DB::table('invoice')->where('code', '=', Session::get('invoiceCODE'))->update([
            'members_id' => Auth::guard('members')->user()->id,
        ]);
        return redirect('checkout');
        } else{
            return redirect($this->redirectTo);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('members');
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $field = filter_var($request->get($this->username()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
            ? $this->username()
            : 'username';

        return [
            $field => $request->get($this->username()),
            'password' => $request->password,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();
        Session::forget('invoiceCODE');

        return redirect('/member/signin');
    }
}
```

any solution for me? this is 
thanks before

Comment: I had this happen once. I had set the password attribute in my User model to automatically encrypt password but I also encrypted the password when the user registered manually within the controller so the stored value was in fact the encrypted version of the already encrypted password. Check to see if this might be the case.

Comment: oke, i have done what you sugested, i will see the result tomorrow, will the user complaining again or not. but i am still curios if this is the problem, why the password only considered wrong after several days and isn't considered wrong all the time?

Comment: If this was the problem, my guess is they registered and were logged in automatically, then after a while they are logged out so it isn;t noticed until they need to login again.

Comment: up up up up up up

Comment: Give me some more data. I want you to do this. Join as a new member. Put an easy password in when joining. After joining, logout then log back in. Let me know if you are able to log in right away. If not, then your password is not being stored correctly. Lets rule this out first before going on to the next step. Let me know if this doesnt make sense.

Comment: hi scott,  i have try to register new member, and logout 10 times after joining, and i try to login at firefox and chrome, and there's no problem logging in, I am very confused with this kind of problem, is there any way to debug a problem like this?

Comment: up up up up upup upup

Comment: With something like this you need to work through and eliminate obvious things. So the login seems to work immediately but changes after a few days. Do you have a change password feature by any change? I wonder if when someone changes a password its changing all of them? Do going with your original question, then those logins will not work in a few days correct? Grab a copy of the stored password and put them in a doc someone to compare in a few days when/if they stop working.

Answer (score -1):

can you see the password changes inside DB? the same situation may also occur even if you reset the encryption key on the env file

Comment: The encryption key has no relation to the Hashing. They are not the same thing!